# How to set CORS headers for fonts in Phoenix?

Tags: heroku, cors, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a Phoenix app, that should serve its static assets (fonts, mainly) to both `www.domain.com` and `subdomain.domain.com`.

The app is hosted on heroku.

How can I set up CORS headers?

I found [this library](https://github.com/whatyouhide/corsica), but it doesn't seems to work on static assets (I think).

I tried to configure it like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.CORS do
  use Corsica.Router

  resource "/fonts/*", origins: ["http://subdomain.domain.com"]
end
```

but the resulting headers are:

```
cache-control:public
content-length:839
content-type:image/svg+xml
date:Sun, 19 Jun 2016 09:40:01 GMT
etag:3AAE04D
server:Cowboy
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the optional `:headers` option to `Plug.Static` and set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `*`.

In `lib/my_app/endpoint.ex`, add the following argument at the end of the `plug Plug.Static` call:

```
headers: %{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*"}
```

Your code should look something like:

```
plug Plug.Static,
  at: "/", from: :my_app, gzip: false,
  only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt),
  headers: %{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*"}
```

Note that this will *not* work if you want to allow more than 1 domain to work (a single domain or `*` would work), as I believe [you have to dynamically calculate the value based on the request's `Origin` header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains) for that, while `Plug.Static` only allows adding a static list of headers.

Comment: Is it possible to set it with an env var? Like in config/prod with something like System.get_env("CORS_ORIGIN") or "${CORS_ORIGIN}" (for released versions) or because of the compilation time of the lib folder we can't? Thanks for your solution by the way!